# SpringFramework schema/integration/websocket namespace does not exist

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-websocket

I am creating a SpringFramework websocket app and I am using examples from the SpringFramework website.

When I used the spring-integration websocket namespace my NetBeans IDE warned that it couldn't find the xml definition at:

http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/websocket/spring-integration-websocket.xsd

I took a look at:

http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/

and discovered that there is no "websocket" directory.

Has this definition been moved or replaced by something or is this by design for some reason?

If it has been moved where can I find it?
If it is just missing from the springframework.org website, where can I find a copy so my IDE will be able to resolve its autocomplete helpers for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We'll take a look why it isn't there. Because WebSockets support has been added since Spring Integration 4.1.

Anyway the IDE should determine XSD from the `spring-integration-websocket` dependency. The XSD is on location `\org\springframework\integration\websocket\config\` within that jar.

Comment: For historical reasons, the online schemas are 1.0.x; changing them would break early applications. As mentioned, the actual schemas are resolved  in the jar from the classpath.

Answer (score 0):

The schemata are delivered with the jars and are listed in the META-INF/spring.schemas file in the jar. (they are not loaded from any website).

Therefore make sure that you have the `spring-integration-websocket.jar` in your classpath.